# how to call IFormsAuthentication interface in unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing

how to call IFormsAuthentication interface in unit testing in asp.net mvc with repositories

Answer (score 0):

You should use a mock object framework such as [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) or [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). The web will give you plenty to read about using mock objects in unit testing.